# how to develop an application in Java/Java EE that allows us to search images which contains some specific words by using a search bar

Tags: java, image, api, jakarta-ee, frameworks

I'm looking for how to develop an application in Java/Java EE that allows us to search images which contains some specific words by using a search bar. The words are inside a picture Such as a picture of a newspaper.

Look, for example we would have a database of pictures then we can search of pictures that contain some keywords, finally the result is five pictures for example, the 5 pictures contain these keywords.

You know we can search and index pdf files by using the framework Alfresco or SOLR. Can we do the same thing with pictures by using some APIS or frameworks ?

Comment: looks like you need OCR

Comment: Thank you Leo I will try this then answer you

Comment: OCR is not an API or a framework ! It's just a software that help you to transfer an image to a text. I don't need that, anyway thanks for your replay and your time

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had images with words to be extracted by an OCR, not a database of images with already curated list of associated keywords.

Comment: Yes it's okey thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly openended question, so I'll share what I know.

It is possible to pull text out of images using a Java port of the c library opencv. A friend of mine used to read text from rendered images of PDF documents. I'd recommend using opencv to pull any text out of these images.

In terms of the database, sql or sqllite are popular and have java libraries. Once you have your image data, use one of these solutions to link the data.

Comment: I have searched about opencv I don't think so it would help me. I need search and index image file. do you have an other solution ? anyway thanks for your replay